# Новые правила для подписок 1 ноября 2020

Tags: android

У меня в приложении есть подписка которая работает нормально. В Google Console пришло уведомление  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прочитал все в соответствующих ссылках, но не совсем понимаю - что от меня требуется, как от разработчика изменить\добавить по коду?! Проверял тестовую подписку через Google Play - можно отменить и возобновить подписку, но возобновить можно только до момента ее окончания. Это правильно?

В интернете тоже не нашел нормальной инфы. В основном все спрашивают тоже, что и я к примеру: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175823/google-play-inapp-billing-v3-action-required-account-hold-mandatory-by-1-no

Кто-то уже обновлял свои приложения под новые правила, подскажите пожалуйста?